# Did all the nxt 2.0 lego content vanish from the Lego website?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I keep finding links to pictures and projects that evidently used to be on an nxt content site at lego. Is all of that information just gone? A site called nxtasy also seems to have vanished. Are there any good sources for nxt project documentation any more?

Comment: What specific kinds of documentation are you looking for?

Comment: I have Robotics Invention system 2. I have this for over 15years. I lost my CD to program Lego. Can we still download from online? I cannot find anywhere. Please help us. Thanks

Comment: Use this link for RIS/expansion packs:
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/718o6673jhpn9/RIS

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer?  Doesn't it seem like a question to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still some NXT stuff on the LEGO website. It is just hidden a little bit. Go to the new Mindstorms website and click on [downloads](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/ddsoftwaredownload/). <strike>Then look for the arrows at the top left of the *Download Archive* section and click the right arrow. You will find a NXT tab.</strike> Edit: The NXT downloads have been moved to the main download tab so they are easy to find now.

NXTasy has become http://www.mindboards.net.